# ASP.net 3.5 Mime mapping

Tags: asp.net

I build my own website ASP.net3.5 that have files with "rdf" extensions, but when I host it on server "aspspider" I can't open rdf files "file not found"
this can be solved by add mime mapping in IIS if I have control on it, 
So is there any other way to solve this proplem such as as elements in web.config?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [there is](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/25/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config.aspx):

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".rdf" mimeType="application/rdf+xml" />
     </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

See [`mimeMap` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689529%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Make sure the mimeType is the one you want.